# Unable to add firebase storage to my SwiftUI app using Cocoapod

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, cocoapods

I'm trying to add firebase to my SwiftUI app using cocoapods. I already added 'Firebase/Auth' and   'Firebase/Firestore' to my podfile and everything was fine. but when I tried to add 'Firebase/Storage' I got error  " CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 31 error(s):"

I tried `pod repo remove trunk` and then `pod install` and now get the same error even when try to add 'Firebase/Auth' and   'Firebase/Firestore'

My pod file

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
 platform :ios, '13.0'

target 'SwiftUI-Chat' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for SwiftUI-Chat
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'Firebase/Firestore'
pod 'Firebase/Storage'
end
```

Error:

```
 [!] CDN: trunk Repo update failed - 31 error(s):
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.1/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.2/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.3/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.4/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.5/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.0.6/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
    CDN: trunk URL couldn't be downloaded: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/cocoa/Specs/3/c/c/FirebaseStorage/1.1.0/FirebaseStorage.podspec.json Response: SSL peer certificate or SSH remote key was not OK
```

Comment: Looks like a pretty straightforward error. I don't think it's anything on your end. You may try another way like Carthage or perhaps Swift Package Manager...not sure if they're 100% ready to roll on SPM, but there is a branch laying around w/ some SPM stuff on it.

Comment: seemed it was a server side issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try again.

This looks like a region-specific issue that was resolved. More detail at https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/9834#issuecomment-636947377